# Does gradient descent and normal equation give the same answer?

Tags: regression

I tried to optimize for a linear regression model using both approaches and they gave me two completely different answers.

My sample data set was:

> df <- data.frame(c(1,5,6),c(3,5,6),c(4,6,8))

Here's the R code I was using to try to calculate gradient descent, perhaps someone can point out the error to me:

```
lm_gradient_descent2 <- function(df,learning_rate, y_col=length(df),scale=TRUE){

n_features <- length(df) #n_features is the number of features in the data set

#using mean normalization to scale features

if(scale==TRUE){

for (i in 1:(n_features)){
  df[,i] <- (df[,i]-mean(df[,i]))/sd(df[,i])
    }
  }
  y_data <- df[,y_col]
  df[,y_col] <- NULL
  par <- rep(1,n_features)
  df <- merge(1,df)
  data_mat <- data.matrix(df)
  #we need a temp_arr to store each iteration of parameter values so that we can do a 
  #simultaneous update
  temp_arr <- rep(0,n_features)
  diff <- 1
  while(diff>0.0000001){
    for (i in 1:(n_features)){
      temp_arr[i] <- par[i]-learning_rate*sum((data_mat%*%par-y_data)*df[,i])/length(y_data)
    }
    diff <- par[1]-temp_arr[1]
    print(diff)
    par <- temp_arr
  }

  return(par)
}
```

When I used excel's regression to test, it gave me the same answer as the normal equation approach. So my guess is there's something wrong with my calculations.

Comment: You probably did something wrong. Check that you are updating your gradient descent correctly, especially the step size. For example, is your gradient descent even converging to something or is it bouncing between two values?

Comment: @AlexR. thanks for the response, I added the code I was using for my calculations, perhaps you are able to tell what's wrong?